# Another SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, swift, ios7

I am getting an error Thread1: signal SIGABRT in the line below, I already tried:

- Product>Clean, Restart Computer
- check all connections to the storyboard
- check if some connection is lost
- the Identifier is set to Cell in the attribute inspector

plus look into many posts in this forum.

After all this I deleted all connections with storyboard and connect again but still get the same error :(

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DefinitionTableViewCell
```

In the console:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:6245

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell2 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Any help is more than welcome Tks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as the exception message suggests, you "must register a nib or a class for the identifier". Try adding this line in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "nameOfYourCustomNib", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
```

Replace the `nameOfYourCustomNib` with your nib name, for example if you have a file `MyCustomCell.xib` then the name would be `MyCustomCell`.

If this fails, try registering a class instead of a nib (remember to delete the first line), by typing:

```
tableView.registerClass(DefinitionTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
```

And the most important thing, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, make sure you check if the cell is `nil`, and if so, create a new `DefinitionTableViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks Fengson, I tried still the same error. :( "nameOfYourCustomNib" what should I put there? :(

Comment: I've had the same error, and there are 2 more things I've tried and each one worked in a different case. You could try both, and tell me if it worked. See my edit.

Comment: the second one works great, Thanks a lot save my day :)